# Java JAX-WS SSL connection reset

Tags: web-services, tomcat, ssl, jax-ws

I have a peculiar problem while contacting a webservice over SSL. I am running my application on a Apache Tomcat instance; I have several instances on different servers. On my test-server I can call the webservice without issues, BUT on one of my other servers it seems like here is a difference. The webservice call fails with the following output:

```
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1371869704 bytes = { 252, 237, 86, 149, 133, 159, 4, 122, 234, 40, 80, 158, 223, 243, 249, 186, 196, 191, 182, 7, 189, 9, 210, 112, 6, 89, 28, 182 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_
ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, 
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CB
C_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, 
sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
***
ajp-bio-8309-exec-38, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 175
**ajp-bio-8309-exec-38, WRITE: SSLv2 client hello message, length = 170**
ajp-bio-8309-exec-38, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
ajp-bio-8309-exec-38, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
ajp-bio-8309-exec-38, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
ajp-bio-8309-exec-38, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
ajp-bio-8309-exec-38, called closeSocket()
ajp-bio-8309-exec-38, called close()
ajp-bio-8309-exec-38, called closeInternal(true)
```

I have generated a keystore with the appropriate certificate.

Like so:

```
keytool -import -file mysite.cer -keystore mykeystore
```

I am importing this into my keystore and, like I said, it works on some of my instances.

I haven't been able to any significant difference between my instances but somehow they act differently when it comes to SSL requests.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was caused by a firewall on the webservice side. Turns out the provider I was using had different policy for their testing environment; the testing environment denied my request over https 443 while their production server did not. Weird.